# Microsoft translator number to words weird behaviour

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

Got an issue here, can't translate properly to "word", it only works on very small numbers.

[image]

[image]

This is how I call the webAPI
https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate?to=zh-chs&text=Nine

I've consulted the docs but I've yet to find something.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512421.aspx)
[COGNITIVE](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#/)

Is there any way of forcing the translate to translate to word and not arabic format ?

Thanks,

Comment: No I don't think you can force it. You can try making a feature request on uservoice https://translatorbusiness.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/topics/118443-text-translation-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no options for controlling semantic behaviors such as number, date/time, etc. The result is dependent on the materials used for training the engine for a particular language, and in this particular case, it appears that for this language pair, word numbers are represented by digits in the result.